# Equation cheat sheet: four columns, and visually linking column 1 and 2 | 3 and 4 across text wraps and line breaks

Tags: line-breaking, two-column, multicol, wrap

I would like to make an equation cheat sheet for my upcoming physics Final. We are allowed one sheet (front and back) with our own notes.

To maximize space and usability I am thinking of a document that is.

- Landscape
- four columns
- Small text

In my mind I see it looking like this (without the actual space for header titles. Just columns with expressions and descriptions. I added the header titles for descriptive purposes.)

```
+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+
|      Col1       |      Col2      |     Col3      |     Col4     |
+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+
| Description 1   | Expression 1   | Description 2 | Expression 2 |
| Description ... | Expression ... | Description n | Expression n |
+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+
```

The part I am having an issue with is figuring out how to relate description 1 with expression 1 in terms of formatting. That is, say a description is really long and wraps a few lines, how to keep the next description and expression visually paired in terms of formatting?

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: Do you want me to post a landscape four column document? I think my description explains what I am trying to do better than posting a borked document using examples I have found online.  If you know of a solution and this is your requisite then I am glad to post a "working document" otherwise it seems like fodder to add this code.

Comment: Some code the compiles and gives some mock data for your table would be great. People are more likely to help you if you show them what you have tried, or what aspects of your question you have managed to solve, as this shows that you are not just asking some one to do all of the work for you. It is also much easier to hep you if you provide some code that shows what you want

Comment: Not saying you're wrong. In this case, I do not want to choose a library or method prematurely and lock someone into a method/style that is the wrong "outfit" for this task on the back of document I just looked up and pieced together. I am not even sure what I am asking is possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule you should always give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). I've used the mock table in the question.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[landscape,8pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X|X|X|X@{}}
     Col1       &      Col2      &     Col3      &     Col4 \\\hline
  Description 1   & Expression 1   & Description 2 & Expression 2\\
  Description ... & Expression ... & Description n & Expression n
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Here is the top of the page that this produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. This is perfect. Sorry for not posting a working example I will make up for it and pass along the good karma and answer some questions (in the same vein) in a forum where I can prove to be a bit more useful!